# Python:Transforming row level items with specific prefix strings into columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a datafrmae as follows:

```
ID  Item_Code    Bidder Desc     Price
1      100       ABC_With Tax      100
2      100      ABC_Without Tax    90
3      100       XYZ_With Tax      95
4      100      XYZ_Without Tax    87
```

What I want:

```
ID    Item_Code Bidder Desc     Price_With Tax     Price_Without Tax
1       100         ABC                100                  90
2       100         XYZ                 95                  87
```

So essentially, we are pivoting / unstacking the original table I guess.

Not able to find any clue. Any thought would be appreciated.

Comment: 110 was associated with both  ABC and XYA, after your transformation it is only related XYZ. While this can be done, you may want to explain the rationle behind it

Comment: Sorry it was typo. Made the changes! Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: pd.concat([df,df['Bidder Desc'].str.split("_",expand=True,)], axis=1).pivot(index=[0,'Item_Code'],columns=1,values='Price')